# When I try to upload a csv file to controller, it always returns a 404

Tags: c#, ajax, .net-core

When I try to upload a csv file to my controller, it always returns 404. I've tried to add, remove, and replace ajax call properties, but nothing solves the problem.

js code

```
        data = new FormData();
        data.append("Csv", files[0]);
      $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Parse',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            async: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (resp) {
                if (resp) {

                    debugger;
                }

            }
        });
```

c# code

```
  [HttpPost]

    public IActionResult Parse(IFormFile Csv)
    {
       
        Db.Db.ParseCsv(Csv);
        return View();
      

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure `/Home/Parse` is the correct URL. Can you show us your routing?

Comment: What is the name of the controller that contains this action method?

Comment: `[Route("Localization")]
 public class HomeController : Controller`

Comment: controller Home i am sure

Comment: Your URL should be `/Localization/Parse` then.

Comment: @DavidG not working too

Comment: It could be a problem related to `Content-Type` header. Why do you set the following property: `enctype: 'multipart/form-data'`? I think it should be removed and instead of it you should have `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'`